# How to override some specific product function?

Tags: magento2, product, overrides, product-images

Is it possible to **override** one specific product function? I need to write a custom function for the **`getImage`** function.

Is there a way to do that in Magento 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a "preference" for the class that contains your function, you can then extend that class in your code and just rewrite the one function that you require. Here's an overview on how to use preferences:

http://www.coolryan.com/magento/2016/01/22/preferences-in-magento-2/

Comment: Looks like I should be able to exactly what I what with this method.